# C strcmp not working

Tags: c, network-programming, strcmp, strcpy

So I have the following code and basically `buffer` is supposed to hold a string, `"NOT FOUND"` which is given by the server I'm connecting to. It is done by the `recvfrom()` system call in the first function block.

The problem is it is still going to my if condition, `if (strcmp(buffer, "NOT FOUND") != 0)`, and not the else block below. I'm not sure whats wrong.

I also checked that the server does return `"NOT FOUND"`, but upon printing buffer, prints: `"NOT FOUNDJ�"`.

`BUFFER_SIZE` is `80`

```
void recvFromServer(int sd, char* buf) {

    struct sockaddr_in6 client;
    socklen_t client_len = sizeof(client);

    int rd = recvfrom(sd, buf, BUFFER_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &client_len);
    if (rd < 0) {
        printf("ERROR: recvfrom() failed\n");
        return;
    }

    char host[BUFFER_SIZE], service[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int r = getnameinfo((struct sockaddr *)&client, client_len, host, sizeof(host),
                    service, sizeof(service), 0 | NI_NUMERICHOST);

    if (r < 0) {
        printf("ERROR: getnameinfo() failed\n");
        return;
    }

}

recvFromServer(sd, buffer);

printf("L %s\n", buffer);
char address[80], port[80];

if (strcmp(buffer, "NOT FOUND") != 0) {
    char *index = strchr(buffer, ' ');
    strncpy(address, buffer, index - buffer);
    address[strlen(address)] = '\0';
    strcpy(port, &buffer[index - buffer + 1]);
    printf("%s\n", address);
    printf("%s\n", port);
    sendMessageUDP(argv[4], sd, address, port);
} else 
    printf("Not Found\n");
```

Comment: What is your current understanding of what a string is, and what `recvfrom` does?

Comment: `address[strlen(address)] = '\0';` means virtually nothing because thinking the definition of string in C, `address[strlen(address)]` should be already `'\0'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add terminating null-character to what you received before treating it as string.

Assuming that declaretion of `buffer` is `char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];`,

```
int rd = recvfrom(sd, buf, BUFFER_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &client_len);
if (rd < 0) {
    printf("ERROR: recvfrom() failed\n");
    return;
}
buf[rd >= BUFFER_SIZE ? BUFFER_SIZE - 1 : rd] = '\0'; /* add this line here */
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks, that works, but could you also please explain what is meant by ? and the other syntax. I've seen it before but I've never used it in coding.

Comment: @user3821306: The `:?` is a ternary (three expression) conditional operator.  You should be able to find it in any C text book, but `(a > b) ? c : d` evaluates the condition (here, `(a > b)`); if it is true, then the overall expression evaluates to `c`; otherwise, it evaluates to `d`.  The parentheses are optional — witness the usage in the answer.